# Can I embed a Microsoft Teams video meeting into my website using an iframe or other technology?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, microsoft-teams, x-frame-options

Can I embed a Microsoft Teams video meeting into my website using an `iframe` or other technology?

When I tried, I got this error:

> Refused to display 'https://teams.live.com/' in a frame because it set
> 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Can it be cheated somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The error message is telling you exactly why not: Microsoft have set a HTTP header in the Teams site which instructs the browser not to load the page into any kind of frame unless that frame is within the teams.live.com website.

The [MDN documentation for X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) says

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites

This is not something you can override - if you could, setting the header would immediately become completely pointless, since anyone with malicious intent would simply choose to ignore it.